# Add new records in typo3 backend is horrible slow. How to optimize it?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

When I create new records (or edit existing) in TYPO3 in need to wait a few minutes before can I can edit anything. Most elements are loaded but they still load some more complex selectbox (with 3000 position for example)

Is there any way to make it lazy (load after click for example) or is there any way to edit a record before it is fully loaded?

Or any other method of optimizing this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: as it is in tags: typo3-8.7.26